# Rails - loops and routes, and getting . instead of /

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, routes

I have three controllers, books, users and contributions. In a view in the books controller I have the following snippet -

```
<%= link_to contrib.user.username, show_users_path(contrib.user_id) %>
```

Which returns /users.n rather than /users/n

```
<%= link_to contrib.user.username, "users/#{contrib.user_id}" %>
```

does the same thing.

I've read SO questions about this problem with nested resources, and with custom routes, but I've simply got my routes set up as resources, as follows -

```
devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
resources :blogs
resources :books
resources :users
resources :contributions
```

In users/index I have the snippet

```
<%= link_to user.username, "users/#{user.id}" %>
```

which works fine. What is going on?

.....

The problem was I'm using an each loop. The whole snippet goes

```
<% if controller.controller_name == "books" %>
  <p><strong>by <%=link_to book.user.username, book.user %></strong></p>
  <% book.contributions.each do |contrib| %>
     <p><%= link_to contrib.user.username, user_path(contrib.user) %></p>
  <%end%>
<% end %>
```

I changed the fourth line to this -

```
<p><%= link_to contrib.user.username, user_path(book.contrib.user) %></p>
```

Which works. Can anyone explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the default path for the show action is object_path(object_id) - there i no default route called show_object_path - I was confusing the path with action.